# Set AngularJS Directive load order not defined on a single DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This is my first post here, usually I can find what I’m looking for before I ask but, if I missed the same question/answer elsewhere sorry. Anyway this is what I have.

I’m working on an Angular project where we have multiple directives not defined on a single DOM like this below(not exactly but a good example)

```
<div  class=”Directive-holder”>

<div Directive-1 ng-show="showDirective1"></div>

<div Directive-2 ng-show="showDirective2"></div>

<div Directive-3 ng-show="showDirective3"></div>

<div Directive-4 ng-show="showDirective5"></div>

(Multiple more below)

</div>
```

Now when I run the project I need these to load in order

Directive-1
Directive-2
Directive-3
Directive-4

But when they run they run random every reload is there a way to set the order of these to stay 1-4 on every load?

It looks like `priority: 0,`   only work on multiple directives defined on a single DOM,

Comment: <div  class=”Directive-holder”>

<div Directive-1 ng-show="showDirective1"></div>

<div Directive-2 ng-show="showDirective2"></div>

<div Directive-3 ng-show="showDirective3"></div>

<div Directive-4 ng-show="showDirective5"></div>

(Multiple more below)

</div>

Comment: Are you using `Gulp` or `Grunt` in your project?

Comment: no not using either

Comment: no not using either @ AndreaM16

Comment: May we know why does the order in which the directives are loaded is important, when those directives are not linked to each other?

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD each directive contains a piece of a form element, like a work flow. So its important that they build an object in steps or the object will be undefined when if come time to set their value. does that make sense ha?

Comment: Why not nest the directives?
First object will be parent. It's template could contain another directive that depends on it, and so on.

Comment: @Sudarshan_SMD I'm going to try to refactor to see if this makes more sense. Thanks